# What happens with AuthenticationException?

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot application with spring-security enabled. I have a custom *AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter* that checks request header for some authentication token set by external system. In case token is absent or invalid corresponding *AuthenticationManager* throws *AuthenticationException*. Looks pretty simple.

My problem is that I'd like to be able to handle this *AuthenticationException* by replying with a 403 (Forbidden) status. How can I do it? I tried adding the following to *WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter*:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.exceptionHandling()
       .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());
    ...
```

but it doesn't work. The issue is that *ExceptionTranslationFilter* that is supposed (if I understand it correctly) to handle these things is the last filter in the default security filter chain and exceptions thrown just never get to it. I'm totally stuck. How is this supposed to work? Please help!

Comment: You need to send 403 response manually from the filter. Or even better - you can provide EntryPoint implementation to your filter. In that way it would be possible to forward user to login page.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" what do you mean exactly? What happens after the exception is thrown, and are you sure that it was thrown in the right part of the filter chain?

Comment: The exception (subclass of Authenticationexception) is thrown from my AuthenticationManager's "authenticate" method. But it never gets to ExceptionTranslationFilter, so no special handling for it. Regarding "the right part of filter chain" - that is what my question is about actually. AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter is located BEFORE ExceptionTranslationFilter in the filter chain. That confuses me, because it means that exceptions thrown from it won't get caught by ExceptionTranslationFilter.

Answer (score 2):

A long time ago you question was done, but I was stucked in the same question without solution, so I decided to explain how to resolve this.

You are allowed to edit the FilterChain, you may put one ExceptionTranslationFilter before your PreAuthenticationFilter as ...

```
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .addFilter(myPreAuthenticationFilter)
        .addFilterBefore(new ExceptionTranslationFilter(
             new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint()), 
             myPreAuthenticationFilter.getClass()
         )
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(authSecuredUrls).authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())
        ;
```

Your AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter getPreAuthenticatedCredentials or getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal methods may throw AuthenticationException if any credential is not provided as ...

```
    if ( !StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter("MY_TOKEN")) ) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("No pre-authenticated principal found in request");
    }
```

Or your AuthenticationManager authenticate method can throw AuthenticationException too.